# Is it possible to use childNodes.nodeValue and innerHTML together?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have a js script that would getElementByTagname. Then, i check it childNodes value.If i use this line of code:

```
var appname= name[i].childNodes[x].nodeValue;
```

If the nodeValue is Pang Shinichi (*Away from home*). The return of the script above became Pang Shinichi (). HTML tag is not being read but instead it was consider as NULL. So, i was thinking if its possible to use childNodes.nodeValue and innerHTML at once.

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your text is spread across several nodes.  For a quick solution, use `textContent` and `innerText` on the parent node instead:

```
var t = "textContent" in document.body ? "textContent" : "innerText",
    appname = name[i][t];
```

Internet Explorer 8 and lower will use `innerText`, whilst most other browsers will use `textContent`.  There are slight differences between the behaviour of the two when it comes to white space, but for most use cases the results are identical.

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7Qsjm/**

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and i find it effective but i found another issue with it. My itallic tag is not anymore loaded. Instead of, it will be displaying  Pang Shinichi (<i>Away from home</i>), it became Pang Shinichi (Away from Home).

Comment: @user1149244: I thought, from your question, that was what you wanted.  Sorry I misunderstood.  Is there a reason you can't use `name[i].innerHTML`?

Comment: innerHTML won't work. Check the sample data:  <span id="approvers_area">  
    <div>Juan Dela cruz <input type="hidden" name="app_id" value="405"/></div>
    <div>Anthony Konno <input type="hidden" name="app_id" value="482"/></div>
    <div>Brayan Adams (<i>You can skip me.</i>) <input type="hidden" name="app_id" value="324"/></div>
    <div>Brady Wind <input type="hidden" name="app_id" value="285"/></div>
    <div>Angela Err <input type="hidden" name="app_id" value="651"/></div>
    </span>

Comment: And the approvers_area will display a dynamic content. But i found your solution helpful.